# Jenkins Pipeline Script Check-in SVN using NPM

Tags: maven, npm, svn, jenkins-pipeline, checkin

I created a Jenkins Snapshot Pipeline for an npm project. If the version inside the
package.json contains -SNAPSHOT, it will increment the prerelease version, so
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT will become 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.0, then -SNAPSHOT.1,...
I did that so it will publish, when there are changes in SVN.
I wrote a script, which is changing the Version in the package.json automatically, according to the prerelease-version.
The only issue I have is, that i can't checkin the package.json file to SVN.
With maven I'm using:

```
sh """mvn -f $pomFileName -Dstyle.color=always -Dusername=\${REDUCTED} -Dpassword=\${REDUCTED} -s path/to/.m2/settings-release.xml \
    -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:$SVNPATH/ -DdeveloperConnectionUrl=scm:svn:$SVNPATH/ \
    scm:checkin -Dmessage=\"Release Message\" \
    scm:tag -Dtag=V_TAGNAME -DtagBase=TAGBASE -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:SVNPATH/trunk"""
```

Is there a way to commit the package.json without maven, with npm?

Thanks in advance.